# Use custom query result as source for Django model (MySQL database)

Tags: mysql, django

I have a database for a lot of structured data. I will perform query among those data.

It will be very helpful when I do the query with a view. I can create a model with the same structure as the view and then use it as a "real" model.

However, in cases when I cannot create a view, can we use Django model to query custom result sets?

For example, in MySQL, we can write query to store the middle result in a list of tuples. And then we can perform the query on the list. Is there anyway we could feed the Django's model with the result of the list of tuple created by a query?

Answer (score 1):

For feeding model with raw SQL query you can use `raw()` method. Take a look at this example (from official reference):

```
class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(...)
    last_name = models.CharField(...)
    birth_date = models.DateField(...)

#...

for p in Person.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM myapp_person'):
    print(p)
```

[Read more here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/sql/)

Comment: Is it possible for situation when the table Person does never exist in the database, instead, I just created the model class for query?

Comment: How do you want to query a table that does not exist now? You will have to prepare a `select` for this so this will be the moment to create a model. I don't think that it is possible in Django to parse query result to Model class object however using cursors and direct DB queries it is possible to create a class dynamically (by fetching result, iterating over it and adding fields to some empty class)

Comment: I have just done a quick test. I realized that it will just works in Django when you perform the raw query and select data from tables with different names from the model. Thanks for your help!